# I am not sure why I keep getting the error Value of type '(AnyObject) -> ()' has no member 'currentTitle'

Tags: swift, xcode

```
@IBAction func Hint(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if Action.currentTitle != Int(rightAnswerPlacement) // this is the line where I keep getting error I posted above 
        {
            Action.isHidden = true // true to hide the button
        
        }
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Hint: UIButton!
    
    
    //Label for qs
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    //button for choices
    @IBOutlet weak var Action: UIButton!
    
    
    @IBAction func Action(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print("Right")
            
        }
        else
        {
            print("Wrong")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is incorrect", message: "Try again!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            currentQuestion -= 1
            //how to record which wrong answer the user is pressing
            //let WrongAnswer = sender.tag.titleLabel?.text
            

        }
```

This is a code for a basic quiz app on Xcode, what I am trying to do with my first few lines of code is trying to make an option disappear once I click another button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the error is that both your button and a function are named `Action`. In the line that gives you error, compiler thinks you are referring to the function (which is of type `(AnyObject) -> ()`) instead of the button. Rename either your function, or your button.

By the way, there are couple of things you should improve in your code:

- by convention, names of types are uppercased, while names of instances should be lowercased
- use more descriptive names for your variables and functions - i.e. `hintButton` instead of `Hint`, `actionButton` instead of `Action` for `UIButton` and `actionButtonTapped` for `func`

Comment: Thanks for your help man. Just another thing cos now I am getting a different error in the same line: 'Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String?' and 'Int' .' I understand it is occurring cos I am comparing a string and an integer in the same statement, would you have any idea how I can solve that? Thanks