# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff0ece07a40" ERROR on xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

```
    for actionButton in actionButtons {
        if actionButton.currentTitle != (String(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            actionButton.isHidden = true // true to hide the button
        }
        }
    }
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var hintButton: UIButton!
    
    
    //Label for qs
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    //button for choices
    @IBOutlet var actionButtons: [UIButton]!
    
    @IBAction func Action(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerPlacement))
        {
            print("Right")
            
        }
        else
        {
            print("Wrong")
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "That is incorrect", message: "Try again!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
            present(alert, animated: true)
            currentQuestion -= 1
            //how to record which wrong answer the user is pressing
            //let WrongAnswer = sender.tag.titleLabel?.text
            
        }
```

Hi, this is a snippet of code for a simple quiz app and I am trying to code for a hint button which when pressed makes one of the choices for every qs in the quiz disappear. My code had no errors until I ran it and saw the error mentioned above in the App.Delegate.swift.The exact error message is 'Thread 1: Exception: "-[Aphasia_app.ViewController Hint:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff0ece07a40" ' . I am quite sure the problem is with my code and not with any connections in the storyboard. Thanks for the help, been stuck at this for two days now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am quite sure the problem is with my code and not with any connections in the storyboard.

No, the problem is indeed a connection. According to a suggestion in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581325/i-am-not-sure-why-i-keep-getting-the-error-value-of-type-anyobject-has) you renamed `Hint` to `hintButton` which does not rename the connection automatically.

In the storyboard delete the dead `Hint` connection and reconnect it to `hintButton`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a ton! My hint button works now unfortunately tho it makes all my options disappear instead of that one. How do I edit the code to make sure only one of my four choices is disappearing?